# Integrating Turbo Modules in React Native with Existing Android and iOS Native Projects

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-bridge, react-native-turbomodule

I'm looking to integrate an existing Android and iOS native project with a new React Native project. I've come across the concept of Turbo Modules in React Native and would like to use them for better performance. The catch is, that the project names on the React Native and native sides might be different.

Is it possible to implement Turbo Modules while integrating the React Native project with existing native code using bridging, as described in this reference link: https://medium.com/@duytq94/integrating-react-native-with-existing-android-and-ios-native-projects-175cc9517c1 ? Will the difference in project names impact the functionality of Turbo Modules? Any insights or guidance on how to make this work would be appreciated.